# Looking for site people can text pictures to upload for beautification

Tags: database

first time here.

I oversee the grounds of a 240 acre public institution. It has beautiful grounds, but there are always maintenance needs.

I'd like to publicize a phone # where people can take a picture of something that needs fixing and it automatically uploads to a site where anyone at the institution can see it, ideally with some text about the location.

For example, a person might be walking by and see a weedy flower bed. They would snap a picture and text it where maintenance and the head of facilities would see it, as would other leaders of the organization. We'd then have an inventory of things that need fixing.

Anything like this?